# PHP File Download - Maximum execution time occurs randomly

Tags: php, download, file-handling, execution-time

It seems I have a problem with file downloading. My logs show the error "Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded" but the requested file is just a little css-file with only 1.64 KB. So it shouldn't take 60 seconds to deliver and unfortunately the error is not exactly reproducable. If I open the url it works perfectly, but my errorlog shows errors occuring (randomly?) on other clients several times. Is there a bug in my code?

```
// this code is from: http://www.richnetapps.com/the-right-way-to-handle-file-downloads-in-php/
// fix for IE catching or PHP bug issue
header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: -1"); // set expiration time
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0"); // browser must download file from server instead of cache
if(substr($filename, -4) == ".css")
{
    $mimeType = "text/css";
}
header("Content-Type: ".$mimeType);
header("Content-length: ".$filesize);

$filehandle = fopen($filename, "rb");
// large file handling:
while(!feof($filehandle))
{
    print(@fread($filehandle, 1024*8));
    ob_flush();
    flush();
    if(connection_status() != 0)
    {
        @fclose($filehandle);
        unlink($filename);
        exit;
    }
}
@fclose($filehandle);
unlink($filename);
exit;
```

The errorline is always within the while-loop, but it's not always the same line.

Thanks for help! :)

Comment: maybe the user doesn't click on **download file** immediately...

Comment: no, in this case there is no download file prompt

Answer (score 1):

Why all this `OB` fuss for a simple css output? I am sure its that connection status check which causes your request to hang sometimes.

```
if(connection_status() != 0)  // that specifically
```

Why do you even need it? You can simply do

```
header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: -1"); // set expiration time
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Content-Type: text/css");
header("Content-length: ".$filesize);
readfile($filename);
```

Comment: this code should be able to handle all kinds of files, so large files as well. I edited the mimetype line in the code to show that I can be something else as well.

Comment: Then those large files can sometimes take more than 60 seconds to parse. And this code should be able to handle that easily. Read more here http://php.net/readfile

Comment: You still don't need all that loop stuff.

Comment: hm but what about the concerns written here: http://www.richnetapps.com/the-right-way-to-handle-file-downloads-in-php/ ? Perhaps I need a simple readfile-way for small files and the loop-way for large files?

Comment: How large are those large files?